# Static code analysis apache camel Spring dsl

Tags: spring, apache-camel, sonarqube, fuseesb, spring-dsl

Iam trying to implement static code analysis for Apache Camel not only for java but also XML based DSL.Is there any SCA Tool available?

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to the Camel routes as you want some kind of analysis of those? As Apache Camel is just regular Java code, then any regular SCA tools you can use

There is a good list on wikipedia

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

That said we are working on a "code/route coverage" tool that you run as part of unit tests, and then it can report which parts of your Java or XML routes have been covered or not. That work is still ongoing, you can follow the ticket:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8657

Comment: Hi Claus,
Thanks for reply Is there any tool where we can define rules for camel coding especially xml  for developers and it shows defects if it don't comply to the rules..like we have sonar qube for Java...

Comment: No there is no such tool. You can validate the XML that its correct according to the Camel XSD schemas. But there is no tool to validate that you do "something not so good".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can certainly create a custom Sonar XPath rule using the XML plug in e.g. testing elements exist with certain attributes.